# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've developed a desktop application using WPF and Entity Framework code-first.

In my application the user can create multiple databases at run-time.

But Entity Framework can't create database if the user isn't admin on his machine.

I need to find a solution that could be done with coding. Management Studio is not installed on the user's machine.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Use a SQL account having `CREATE DATABASE` rights.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It means I've to enable SA account for example ?

Comment: yes. You have to use administrative account

Comment: You can grant a users/role permission to create a database by doing GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO AnAppUser

Comment: @Brian Is this TSQL Command ? Is this command executable if the user isn't admin on his machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to execute this T-SQL command using an account that *does* have administrative rights, such as sa:

```
USE master;
EXECUTE sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourAppUserLogin', @rolename = N'dbcreator';
```

Replace `YourAppUserLogin` with the login the application user uses to connect to the database.